# FTP file manager Magento 2

Tags: magento2

And when frontend calls it, doesn't answer. Meaning a "css" or "js" 400 error.

Magento works just fine, but it doesn't run commands like di:compile because it can't find them in the directories.

And going to the directories they are found only in the form of shortcuts, what will it be?

here is a print: http://prntscr.com/ot77ql

Thanks in advance. Sorry for the bad English.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run a command like setup:di:compile, first ensure that you are in the root directory. Try entering the command like this

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Yes it goes well, till deploy it: http://prntscr.com/ot7kfa